# how to draw a truncated cone in c#

Tags: c#, 3d, geometry

I have a program that gets 2 radii, rotation, translation matrix, but when drawing a cone I have a problem: the circles go beyond the generatrix of the cone, I feel stupid
but I don't see where the error is

```
 for (double l = 0.5; l <= 1.5; l = l + 0.1)
            {
                R = (R1 + (R2 - R1) * (l - 0.5));
                z = l;
                y = -R;
                double alpha = 0;
                double dalpha = Math.PI / 5;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {

                    circle_z[i] =  l * R;

                    circle_y[i] = R * Math.Cos(alpha);

                    circle_x[i] = R * Math.Sin(alpha);
                    alpha += dalpha;
                }

                y = R;
                alpha = 0;
                dalpha = Math.PI / 5;
                for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    circle_z[i] = l * R;

                    circle_y[i] =R * Math.Cos(alpha);

                    circle_x[i] = R * Math.Sin(alpha);
                    alpha += dalpha;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    double sina = Math.Sin(degree_a);
                    double sinb = Math.Sin(degree_b);
                    double sinc = Math.Sin(degree_c);
                    double cosa = Math.Cos(degree_a);
                    double cosb = Math.Cos(degree_b);
                    double cosc = Math.Cos(degree_c);
                    x = circle_x[j];
                    y = circle_y[j];
                    z = circle_z[j];

                    circle_x[j] = (x * cosb * cosc + y * sina * sinb * cosc - y * sinc * cosa + z * sinc * sina/2 + z * sinb * cosa * cosc) * measure * 10;
                    circle_y[j] = ((x * sinc * cosb + y * cosa * cosc + y * sinb * sina * sinc - z * sina * cosc + z * sinb * sinc * cosa) * measure * 10) + dl + 263;
                    circle_z[j] = (-x * sinb + y * cosb * sina + z * cosa * cosb) * measure * 10 ;


                }

                if (l==0.5)
                { Array.Copy(circle_x, circle_first_x, 19); Array.Copy(circle_y, circle_first_y, 19); Array.Copy(circle_z, circle_first_z, 19); }
                
                for (int q = 0; q < 19; q++)
                {
                    gr.DrawLine(MyPen, Convert.ToInt32(circle_y[q]), Convert.ToInt32(circle_z[q]), Convert.ToInt32(circle_y[q + 1]), Convert.ToInt32(circle_z[q + 1]));
                }
                gr.DrawLine(MyPen, Convert.ToInt32(circle_y[19]), Convert.ToInt32(circle_z[19]), Convert.ToInt32(circle_y[0]), Convert.ToInt32(circle_z[0]));
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNZA7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jzai.png)

I tried to add coefficients to the formulas, but it didn’t work(